# Makefile error while integrating R and kdb

Tags: kdb

I am using the trial version on Linux. I copied all the files from `kx` svn but when I run the make file I keep getting errors in `k.h`. Is it a `kx` version error?

```
/usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD gcc -g -O -fPIC -m64   -shared -D KXVER=3 -I. -I/usr/share/R/include base.c c.o -lpthread -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR -o qserver.so  
In file included from base.c:11:0:  
./k.h:1:1: error: expected identifier or â(â before â<â token  
./k.h:20:5: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before â&â token  
./k.h:20:13: error: expected identifier or â(â before numeric constant  
./k.h:20:18: error: invalid digit "9" in octal constant  
./k.h:20:34: error: invalid suffix "d" on integer constant  
./k.h:20:40: error: invalid suffix "h" on integer constant  
./k.h:27:17: error: expected identifier or â(â before â<â token  
 In file included from base.c:11:0:  
./k.h:31:150: error: expected identifier or â(â before â-â token  
./k.h:31:167: error: expected identifier or â(â before â-â token  
./k.h:31:167: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:215: error: expected identifier or â(â before â&â token  
./k.h:31:215: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:224: error: expected identifier or â(â before â-â token  
./k.h:31:224: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:285: error: expected identifier or â(â before â&â token  
./k.h:31:285: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:294: error: expected identifier or â(â before â-â token  
./k.h:31:294: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:356: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before â-â token  
In file included from base.c:11:0:  
./k.h:31:603: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before â-â token  
./k.h:31:603: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:693: error: expected identifier or â(â before â&â token  
./k.h:31:693: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:700: error: expected identifier or â(â before â&â token  
./k.h:31:700: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:707: error: expected identifier or â(â before â&â token  
./k.h:31:707: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:714: error: expected identifier or â(â before â&â token  
./k.h:31:714: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:722: error: expected identifier or â(â before â-â token  
./k.h:31:722: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:766: error: expected identifier or â(â before â&â token  
./k.h:31:766: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:773: error: expected identifier or â(â before â&â token  
./k.h:31:773: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:780: error: expected identifier or â(â before â&â token  
./k.h:31:780: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:787: error: expected identifier or â(â before â&â token  
./k.h:31:787: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:795: error: expected identifier or â(â before â-â token  
./k.h:31:795: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:987: error: expected identifier or â(â before â&â token  
./k.h:31:987: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:995: error: expected identifier or â(â before â&â token  
./k.h:31:995: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:1004: error: expected identifier or â(â before â-â token  
./k.h:31:1004: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:1050: error: expected identifier or â(â before â&â token  
./k.h:31:1050: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:1058: error: expected identifier or â(â before â&â token  
./k.h:31:1058: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:1067: error: expected identifier or â(â before â-â token  
./k.h:31:1067: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:1110: error: expected identifier or â(â before â&â token  
./k.h:31:1110: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:1117: error: expected identifier or â(â before â&â token  
./k.h:31:1117: error: stray â#â in program  
./k.h:31:1124: error: expected identifier or â(â before â&â token
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trial version is 32 bit, but you trying to compile with "-m64". Could you try -m32 or just remove that

Comment: That was something i thought too but it wasn't that. I needed to create the c directory and copy the common.c etc. files along with http://code.kx.com/wsvn/code/kx/kdb%2B/c/c/?#a13bd25ee24546baceff884a3804f0ecc.